# How to use pagination in rails 3.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm new in RoR, and I want to include pagination in my application.

Which is the best way to perform this task? Please suggest me. Is it possible to use `will_paginate` gem in rails 3.2.3 ?

If yes, in which method I should include:

```
Post.where(:published => true).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')  

Post.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use `will_paginate` gem in rails 3.2.3 applications.

And the code will depends on what each action will perform.

The code below usually goes on a `#index` method, in your `PostsController`.

```
@posts = Post.where(:published => true).paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('id DESC')
```

So, in your `posts/index.html.erb` view file you can use the following code to display the pagination links:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Comment: [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) is the other mainstream solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when i use this coed, then following error occur:  undefined mentho 'paginage' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x....>

Comment: That's because the method calls `paginate`, not `paginage`

Comment: Make sure you have added `gem 'will_paginate'` in your `Gemfile` and run the command `bundle install` at your terminal.

Comment: No, you don't have to add anything to the `model` to get this working.