# Rails will_paginate using :conditions, only if param present in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i'm trying to achieve paginated list of records from database, with conditions given in url.

for example: if url is like: `?name=Michael&age=20`
it should display all Michaels with age 20 etc.

But if url is like `&age=20`, it should display all people with age 20 and ignore the "name" parameter.

I'm paginating 2 lists on 1 page, both come from same model, only vary by position, so i've got 2 paginations defined in my controller:

```
@boss = Person.paginate(:page => params[:boss_page], :conditions => "position = 1")
@manager = Person.paginate(:page => params[:manager_page], :conditons => "position = 2")
```

How to now add conditions from URL only if param is present in it?

I was trying this way:

```
conditions = []
conditions << [ "age = ?", params[:age] ] if params[:age].present?
```

but it gives me error when I pass param in URL:

```
undefined method `%' for ["age = ? ", "1"]:Array
```

The next question is how to merge conditions from this array with condition "position = 1"?

UPDATE: I understand how to do pagination with conditions, I just don't get what is best idea to specify conditions based on GET parameters.
I could always do it like this:

```
if params[:age].present?
@boss = version with age conditons
else if params[:age].present? and params[:name].present?
@boss = version with age and name
else if params[:name].preset?
@boss = version with name only
```

but I believe that in rails it can be done simpler.

Comment: For this problem  [this link help you.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867977/how-to-use-pagination-in-rails-3-2-3

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally I did it in another, simpler for me way:

```
@p = Person.scoped
@p = @p.where(:age => params[:age]) if params[:age].present?
@p = @p.where(:name => params[:name]) if params[:name].present?

@boss = @p.paginate(:page => params[:boss_page], :conditions => "position = 1")
@manager = @p.paginate(:page => params[:manager_page], :conditons => "position = 2")
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Tomasz' answer is the right thing to do here - and will result in much cleaner code

Answer (score 4):

First option: you can glue the conditions based on passed parameters manually, building custom named scopes that'll add a where if the passed parameter isn't empty (example from one old project):

```
# custom scope in model
# call in controller by Model.email_contains(params[:email])
def self.email_contains(searched_email)
  if(searched_email.blank?)
    all # scoped
  else
    where(:email => searched_email)
  end
end
```

Second option, just use ransack (or its predecessor, meta_search): https://github.com/ernie/ransack

Answer (score 0):

```
@boss = Person.where(:position => 1).paginate(:page => params[:boss_page])
@manager = Post.where(:position => 2).paginate(:page => params[:manager_page])
```

Comment: I know how to do this simple condition. I need a way to add params from url based on their presence.